# Different Account page layouts, what are they?

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout

I am trying to configure the page layout for account. When I go to object manager -> Account -> Page Layouts I see 8 different page layouts. What are they? I didn't expect to see 8. I am wondering which one I need to edit, or edit all 8?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Salesforce, you can configure multiple page layouts per object, and they can be assigned by record type and profile. This allows administrators to show only relevant information for users based on their profile and the type of account is being viewed. Unfortunately, we can't tell you what each layout represents. You may want to look at the Page Layout Assignments button at the top of the page to see how layouts are assigned. You'll need to modify each layout you need to modify independently, which means figuring out exactly what each layout is intended to do. You may need to modify just one layout, or possibly more than one.

Comment: Thanks specially for hinting the page layout assignments.

Comment: @apadana You're welcome! Always glad to assist where I can.